# JavaScript: filter array of objects by another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to filter some objects based on another array of objects. So I'm getting data from an API. These are for example receipts:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Cookies",
    },
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "test2",
    "category": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Candy",
    },
  }
]
```

Then I'm trying to filter the objects on the category name based on another array of categories.
I've created a function for this:

```
function onSelectCategory(category) {
  let receiptsList = receipts.filter((a) =>
    a.category.includes(category.name)
  );
  setReceiptsView(receiptsList);
  setSelectedCategory(category);
}

const category = [ { "id": 2, "name": "Candy" } ];
onSelectCategory(category);
```

When I run this function, I get an empty Array `[]`. I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to be more clear, what's ``category`` param like? is it the array of objects?

Comment: @MajedBadawi Thank you for your response, the last code block in my post shows what parameter ```category``` is.

Comment: Ok, just to confirm that I understood your problem, you want to keep ``receipts`` which category names are in ``category`` param items right?

Comment: @MajedBadawi Yes, I only want to show the ```receipts``` whose category is the same as what comes in via the ```category``` param

Comment: the comparison is based on the name right?

Comment: @MajedBadawi Yes

Comment: Ok, I believe my answer solves your issue, feel free to drop questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the param seems to be an array of objects, you need to use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for comparison instead:

```js
const receipts = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "test", "category": { "id": 1,  "name": "Cookies" } },
  { "id": 2, "name": "test2", "category": { "id": 2, "name": "Candy" } }
];
const categories = [ { "id": 2, "name": "Candy" } ];

const receiptsList = receipts.filter(({ category }) => 
  categories.some(({ name }) => name === category.name)
);

console.log(receiptsList);
```

Another solution using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const receipts = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "test", "category": { "id": 1,  "name": "Cookies" } },
  { "id": 2, "name": "test2", "category": { "id": 2, "name": "Candy" } }
];
const categories = [ { "id": 2, "name": "Candy" } ];

const categorySet = new Set(categories.map(({ name }) => name));

const receiptsList = receipts.filter(({ category }) => 
  categorySet.has(category.name)
);

console.log(receiptsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `category` (the parameter) is a string, the issue is that you are attempting to get the attribute `name` from the string, when you should be comparing the string to the object.

Try this:

```js
a.category.name == category;
```

instead of

```js
a.category.includes(category.name)
```

I may be wrong aboout assuming that category is a string, please clarify by telling us what the parameter `category` is equal to.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you help. The Category parameter is equal to an array. See the last piece of code in my post above.